# gevent - hub.loop.reinit() does not work after fork

Tags: python, gevent

The `do_magic` function would be called twice in the following example, both in parent and child process.

My confusion is the `os.fork` has been replaced with `gevent.fork`, and `hub.loop.reinit()` would be called in child process. If so, why `do_magic` still be called in child process?

```py
import gevent

from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

import os, time


def do_magic():
    print 'magic...'


def main():
    g = gevent.spawn_later(1, do_magic)

    pid = os.fork()
    if pid != 0:  # parent
        g.join()
    else:
        gevent.get_hub().loop.reinit()
        time.sleep(3)


main()
```